# How to pass Date type to CreateSQLQuery

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hi I am using hibernate in Java. I `save` a row in SOrder Table then I want to update it. so I use this code:

```
s.beginTransaction();
s.save(ordered[i]);
s.getTransaction().commit();
s.beginTransaction();
SOrder so = (SOrder) s.createSQLQuery("select * from SOrder where Created_Time=?")
                .addEntity(SOrder.class)
                .setParameter(0, ordered[i].Created_Time)
                .uniqueResult();
so.Pay_Status="Payed";
so.Response_Code="00";
s.update(so);
s.getTransaction().commit();
```

`save` Method works correctly  but when I `Select *` null returns to `so`, but Created_Time is just that one which saved before.
is there any special way to pass `Date` Type to the CreateSQLQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `=` operator, `parameter date` must be same the date form DB, exactlly. I think, it is like a risk using `=` operator for date parameter in `JPQL` or `hql`.
I suggest to use `>` or `<` or `BETWEEN`operator.

```
WHERE Adate > Bdate                     => Adate is before Bdate
WHERE Adate < Bdate                     => Adate is after Bdate
WHERE Cdate BETWEEN Adate AND Bdate     => Cdate is between Adate and Bdate
```

Comment: yes I want them to be Exactly the same, I saved `Created_Time` itself and it has no reason to return null. Thanks to your answer but I changed the solution and I don't need it more.